# change the return of a method, leave it the same for every situation

Tags: php, oop

Ok so i have a method that will always produce a multi dimensional array. Is it good programming practice to change the output of that method like so:

```
            //$arr is a multi dimensional array that can sometimes contain a single array with a single object
            //Or sometimes return multiple arrays in the parent array, and even sometimes return an array of an array with multiple objects.

            if(sizeof($arr)==1){
                //doesnt need to be 2D reduce to 1D
                $arr = reset($arr);
                if(sizeof($arr)==1){
                    //1D isnt necassary as its a single object reduce!!
                    $arr = reset($arr);
                }else{
                    //return is a one dimensional array
                }
            }else{
                //2D has multiple arrays inside lets check if thos arrays can be reduced to single objects
                foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
                {
                    if(sizeof($value)==1){
                        //array is single object reduce so parent array becomes a mixed single object and arrays
                        $arr[$key] = reset($arr[$key]);
                    }else{
                        //is array
                    }
                }
            }
```

If its ok to have such a practice is their a better way to accomplish this task?

this is inside a method of a class.  My primary question is if doing this is acceptable.  Secondary is if it is is their a better way.

Comment: The question should be: what do you expect the function to return? Define input and output, period.

Comment: Well my thought was to make it easier on the back end when this method is caked and it only has a single object in a array, to return just that so the cost calling the method wouldn't have to adjust the return.  I guess I'm trying to make a catch all situation that will fit every need.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "fit all". Figure out what you *want*, what you *expect* that function to return. That's all.

Comment: OK, put that in an answer in I'll answer it thanks

Comment: Would it be acceptable to have an optional argument to change the output of the method? IE in this situation the method always produces a 2d array, if i put an Optional Argument to allow the method to return a single array or a single object.

Comment: Sure, that's done a lot, e.g. `json_encode(.., true/false)`. The important point is that the output is predictable and defined based on the input arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your design it is hard to tell; but in general I would suggest not to do it. Keeping the returned data structure uniform will make processing of the results  much easier, because you will be able to traverse the returned result always with the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not what you want this function to do, but **what you plan to do with the data later.** In my experience, having a consistent structure (2-dimensional array) is far more convenient than having arrays of different depths. If your 2-dimensional array only has one row, what's the problem? Your top-level loop will run once and return. If you have different array shapes, the rest of your code will need to detect and handle all of them.

In fact I sometimes write code that does the opposite: If a function can accept a single string or a list of strings, internally I immediately convert the single string into a list of length one. Then the rest of the code only has one case to handle.